# Using keyring to automatically authenticate with wget

Tags: command-line, scripts, password, wget

My university offers all of the curriculum online and available for everyone that has a username and password. So naturally i wrote a shell script to just crawl in every needed course and download all of its contents, the problem is though in the authentication. So i figured the username and password of my account isn't so important to keep secure so i hard coded it in the shell script i wrote. however i recently learned about keyrings and still learning and i found that all my passwords is stored there safely. Therefore i want the wget script to be able to grab the password for my university from the passwords stored in the keyring securely(Because of Chromium). what can i do?

```
wget  -c -k --no-parent -r -l  5 --user=$name --password=$password $extrao `cat ~/bin/university/update-links`
```

$extrao is the extra arguments i might add during execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

I use the following command to get my password from the key ring

```
password=`keyring get GUC mohamed.ezzatmahmoud`
```

where GUC is the name of the keyring object

the i use the password as shown in the question.